# Python print_usage and print_help not printing optional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using the following code

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

if len(sys.argv)==1:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)


group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group.add_argument(
        "-v","--version",
        dest="ver",
        action='store_true'
)
group.add_argument(
        "-p","--pin",
        dest="pin",
)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

But, the arguments are never listed. If no argument is passed, I want the same output as if  the --help argument is passed.

I've tried print_help and print_usage, they work the same. I have a feeling the arguments I'm expecting (there are more than the one shown here, I'm trying to save a bit of space) are not being recognised properly, as -h is shown as an optional argument while the others are not.

I hope I've explained myself clearly, been looking for two days now and can't find a fix.

Comment: I didn't quite make that clear. If I call the program with no arguments, -h is listed as an optional argument, but the others are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `print_help()` too early, try:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group.add_argument(
        "-v","--version",
        dest="ver",
        action='store_true'
)
group.add_argument(
        "-p","--pin",
        dest="pin",
)

if len(sys.argv)==1:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: `sys.argv` is just what I was looking for. Cheers.